# Confusion in a proof of the Neyman-Fisher factorization theorem in Jun Shao

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I'm reading Mathematical Statistics by Jun Shao. The proof I'm talking about if on page 104. The statement reads:

> Suppose that $X$ is a sample from $P\in\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal P$ is a family of probability measures on $(\mathbb R^n, \mathcal B^n)$ dominated by a $\sigma$-finite measure $\nu$. Then $T(X)$ is sufficient for $P\in\mathcal P$ if and only if there are nonnegative Borel functions $h$ (which does not depend on
>   $P$) on $(\mathbb R^n, \mathcal B^n)$ and $g_{\small P}$ (which depends on $P$) on the range of T such that
>   $$\frac{dP}{d\nu}(x)=g_{\small P}(T(x))h(x)$$

A paragraph later, the author suddenly defines:

> Let $g_{\small P}(T)$ be the Radon-Nikodym derivative $dP/dQ$ on the space $(\mathbb R^n, \sigma(T), Q)$

Where $Q$ is a previously introduced measure, a countable convex combination of $P_i\in\mathcal P$ which dominates $\mathcal P$.

What does this mean? How can we "define" something that contains $T$ in it? It can't be that the author means just $g_{\small P}$ and not $g_{\small P}(T)$, since if this $g_{\small P}$ is something we want to compose with $T$, then it needs to be defined on the range of $T$, not on $\mathbb R^n$ (the underlying probability space).

Answer (score 1):

> **Fact** If a random variable $X$ is $\sigma(T)$ measurable, then there exists a measurable function $g$ such that $X = g(T)$.

So it would be more courteous to write, "Let $X_P = dP/dQ$ on $\sigma(T)$. Since $X_P$ is $\sigma(T)$-measurable, then $X = g_P(T)$ for some measurable $g_P$".

Comment: The $\sigma(T)$-measurability of $X_P$ depends on the sufficiency of $T$?

Comment: @JackM, no, why? The Radon-Nikodym derivative is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra where the measures are defined. If they are defined on $\sigma(T)$, then it is $\sigma(T)$-measurable. This has nothing to do with sufficiency.

Comment: I see, so the RM derivative is actually different depending on which sigma algebra is taken. I didn't realize.

Comment: In that case, though, why can we not just set $g_P=dP/d\nu$ on $\sigma(T)$ and $h=1$?

Comment: @JackM, the author expresses conditional probability with respect to one measure ($P$) through that with respect to another measure ($Q$). If you used $\nu$ instead of $Q$, what would be the "conditional measure"?
So yes, you could take $\nu$ instead of $Q$ if $\nu$ were a probability measure. (I will also look into my lectures now: I have a feeling that this can be written simpler.)

Comment: I have looked, it's the same (but it's simple enough, I guess).

Comment: I see, so if we set $g_P=(dP/d\nu)_{\sigma(T)}$, the identity $dP/d\nu=g_P$ isn't true because on the left hand side the sigma algebra is assumed to be the ambient sigma algebra on the space, correct? So we need the factor $h$ in order to somehow correct for that deficiency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65071/discussion-between-zhoraster-and-jack-m).